# jQuery Dialog Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog, opacity

I work with jQuery and I want to add css opacity on jQuery dialog, but content must show normally

[image]

In other word I want to background must be transparent and words and button must show normally

Comment: Add code and Fiddle please.

Comment: You can set background opacity only if using background color. Of course, you could use a background image semi transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS property 'opacity' will make every child transparent also.

You can use instead `background-color` and use `rgba` for that on the dialog div (`.ui-dialog` if I'm not mistaken), for example:

```
.ui-dialog {
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

That means a white color (255,255,255) with half opacity (0.5, goes from 0 to 1, 0 meaning invisible, 1 meaning solid).

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard without code, but since I'm in a good mood, I will give it a try.

You probably have an element that is the dialog, I am guessing `<div id="dialog">...</div>`. You can set the alpha opacity for the background like this:

```
#dialog {
     background: rgb( 255, 0, 0 ); /* fallback for not-rgba-supporting browsers */
     background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}
```

Change 0.5 to what the desired opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code for dialog div-

```
/* default fallback */
background: rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
/* nice browsers */
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
/* IE 6/7 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF);
/* IE8 */    
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF, endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)";
```